# How do you run Web Tests during a Team Build (for TFS 2010)?

Tags: tfsbuild

I have a number of solutions in TFS 2010 and happily building them with Team Build, including running unit tests defined in assemblies.

For one solution, I have added some Web Tests (defined in files with the extension ".webtest"). I can successfully run these Web Tests locally from Visual Studio 2010 but cannot get them to execute during a Team Build.

In the Team Build Definition, I have tried changing the "Test assembly file specification" value to "`*test*.dll;*.webtest`" but this fails to pick up the Web Tests. I can see that the .webtest files have been copied under the "Binaries\Debug" directory (same place as the unit tests) so I'm a bit puzzled why they are not found.

What am I missing? How do you get the .webtest files to run under a Team Build?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the FileSpec filter, only include the *.webtest (removing the *test*.dll;).  For the Web Performance Tests, the WebTest and LoadTest files are the test containers.  This is a difference from Unit Tests, which have a DLL as their container.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this yet, but I notice that web tests appear in the Test Lists window. Try creating a test list including the web tests, then specify to run the test list instead of just the test assemblies.

Answer (score -1):

Unless I misunderstood your needs, I think you would be fine if you simply add another Automated Test Assembly spec :
[image]
**EDIT**
In order to find this dialog :
Right-click on the Build definition & select "Edit build definition". Go to "Process" and expand "2.Basic" > "Automated Tests" by clicking the below circled control:
[image]

Depending on your build process template, this might be placed in a different "Process"-section, or might even be missing. The one presented above applies for the "DefaultTemplate".

Comment: The web tests aren't defined in assemblies, they are in XML files with a ".webtest" extension. However, where is that dialog box?

Comment: I get a different dialogue box, not sure why, Visual Studio versions? Anyway, I have gone down this route already. The Web Tests have a ".webtest" extension, they are not assemblies so a "*.webtest*.dll" filter does not work. I need "*.webtest" which I have already tried.

Answer (score -1):

We are using Selenium for our ui testing.  We use a custom build process template which deploys the application and database changes and then uses MSTest.exe to run the ui tests contained in published assemblies.

This requires that the build agent is running in interactive mode on the console and is left logged in, as a consequence we have to use VNC to get to the build server not rdp.

Hope this help....

Comment: -1: this doesn't actually address the question (Visual Studio web tests)